# How do you return a MySQL query result from a node REST API

Tags: node.js

The MySQL JavaScript api is asynchronous.

If I try to write the filling REST Endpoint it fails as the call to MySQL is asynchronous.

```
@endpoint
String getSometing(){

RetVal = MySQL.asynchApiQuery(“someSql”)

return RetVal;
}
```

It will fail as `RetVal` will not be populated when the function returns.

I’ve spoken to a number of people who rave about JavaScripts asynchronous capabilities yet they have been unable to solve this simple synchronous problem

I’m hoping for a simple answer but so far all I’ve got is observable,promise, subscribe, continuation all of which cannot return the query as a promise simply creates a new thread that cannot be associated with the invoked of the REST api.

Any answer to this should return RetVal and not simply print it.

Look forward to a simple answer.

Comment: You should put the actual code here, like the route being called, how you are sending dat to the client, etc. You don't need promises or observables, you can do this with a callback easily, but it wont be with a return the way you are thinking

Answer (score 0):

It's asynchronous but it has something named "callback functions". You can use them to decide what's going to happen with data after a mysql query

Example:

```
db.query("sqlquery",(err,data)=>{console.log(data)})
```

Comment: Hi Helen thanks for the reply but your answer simply logs the data to the console. If that line of code was wrapped in a function then how would you return data as per my pseudo code?